# Can someone help me with this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

```
def positioning
  tasks = Painting.all.order(:position)
  increment = false
  tasks.each do |t|
    if !increment && t.position == self.position
      increment = true
      t.position += 1
      t.save
    elsif increment
      t.position += 1
      t.save
    end
  end
end
```

This method is for a `before_save` callback, and works when I add a new painting, but it's doing something wrong incrementing the other objects position and later when I want to update any object this is a problem.

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want the method to do? I'd say it's a logic error but honestly I don't know what logic you're attempting...

Comment: i want to insert a paint at an specific position, given by a position field, and after the insertion all the paintings with a higher position should move

Comment: ah, so what you're seeing is the position incremented for the ones before the insertion as well? sorry for 20 questions--I just want to make sure I understand before I attempt an answer

Comment: btw, that's not my down vote. I'll always explain why I down voted.

Comment: no exactly, i want to increment the position of the objects with a higher position, so the objects with lower position dont change their position

Comment: Perhaps change your loop to start at the one you have in hand (self.position) and go to the end? that would vastly simplify your loop block...let me think on how that might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1 using update_attribute

```
paintings = Painting.where(:position >=self.position)
paintings.each do |painting|
  painting.update_attributes(:position, painting.position + 1)
end
```

Version 2 using hash

```
paintings = Painting.where(:position >=self.position)
paintings.each do |painting|
  paintingHash = Hash.new
  paintingHash["position"]=painting.position+1
  painting.update(paintingHash)
end
```

The description is for version 2

line 1
find all paintings with position higher than current

line 2
start an itteration through the selected paintings

line 3
create new hash used for updating

line 4 
assign value to a variable in the hash equaling to origional position +1

line 5 
execute update

line 6 end he iteration

Comment: I like the first line. I'm not sure what the hash part is for though.

Comment: you use a hash as a selection of variables for update IE. name, price, position etc. update witll require it as it passes it as params

Comment: can you just use `painting.update_attribute(:position, painting.position + 1)` ?

Comment: you could turn this into a 2 line chunk of code if that last idea works. then I'd be forced to vote this answer up :)

Comment: you could. but i prefer hashes as allows for cleaner look and hasnt failed me ever before

Comment: updating with the update creates a huge chunk of sql with a large hash. Also won't it overwrite any nil values? using update_attribute generates a tiny bit of SQL. Also, if you're only updating a single attribute isn't it clearer to call it out in the actual save more explicitly?

Comment: there's no specific rails flag on here, but if you want the simpler SQL you can do `painting.update_attributes(position: painting.position + 1)`. that works in Rails 4 just fine

Comment: never really thought of it. [Update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) has had issues being deprecated and being returned in later stages. As it is available now i will update my answer now

Comment: I think it being deprecated is as great reason not to use it if the OP is using Rails 4 or beyond. Totally valid comment. I think my previous comment will address it.

Comment: so should i return it to hash?

Comment: I up voted your answer. I also enjoyed the discussion. Thanks!

Comment: If you want Rails 4 and Beyond you can just add an 's' to update_attribute and change the parameter to be a single hash entry in your current solution

Comment: update_attributes is Deprecated since 2.3.8 http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

Comment: That's the one on ActiveRecord::Base. It was moved to ActiveRecord::Persistence:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes

Comment: but theres another problem when i want to update any object position to a lower one..for this exact case i would need to swap the positions

Comment: for updating position i used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aBsUkJMbmE sorting the list vertically. the solution i provided is for creation in all reality

Comment: but im using rails admin as back-end, so if i could apply this tutorial to use it on rails admin will be great, any ideas??

Comment: sorry dude have no experience with rails admin. I prefer to code most from base.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
def positioning
  tasks = Painting.all.order(:position)
  increment = false
  tasks[self.position..-1].each do |t|
    t.position += 1
    t.save
  end
end
```

This allows you to effectively loop through only the ones you want to increment. Since you already have all the tasks in hand from the first line, this doesn't cost anything more that I can tell.

I'm also not entirely sure if your position is 0 based or 1 based. my code assumes 0 based but if not you'll need to tweak that indexing line.

Comment: Personally I like the version 1 answer that @AAnkudovich provided in his answer.

Comment: i find a gem calls acts_as_list, i think this gem can solve my problem but i dont understand the documentation about how to config the model